# connecting to server with android

Tags: android, json, connection

I am new to android and I want to connect to json files but when i try this code but it don't connect , and when I run it in my phone when i want to work , it get me nooo in logcat according that I said to do it when it has problem connecting to server , thank you

```
public class LastFMHelper {

public static final String LastFMMetroTrackChartUrl=
        "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getmetrotrackchart&country=united+states&metro=denver&format=json&api_key=bc8ae5008414312b31e8c23f684d67cc";
private static final int HTTP_STATUS_OK = 200;
private static byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
private static final String logTag="LastFMHelper";


public static class ApiException extends Exception
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID= 1L;

    public ApiException (String msg)
    {
        super(msg);
    }

    public ApiException(String msg, Throwable thr)
    {
        super(msg, thr);
    }

}

protected static synchronized String downlaodFromServer (String ...params) throws ApiException {
    String retval= null;
    String metro = params[0];

    String url= LastFMMetroTrackChartUrl + "&metro" +metro;

    Log.d(logTag,"Fetching"+url);

    HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    try{

        HttpResponse responce = client.execute(request);
        StatusLine status = responce.getStatusLine();
        if(status.getStatusCode()!=HTTP_STATUS_OK)
        {
            throw new ApiException("Invalid responce from last.fm"+status.toString());
        }

        HttpEntity entity = responce.getEntity();
        InputStream ist = entity.getContent();
        ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int readcount =0;
        while((readcount= ist.read(buff)) != -1)
        {
            content.write(buff,0,readcount);
        }
        retval= new String (content.toByteArray());
    }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d(logTag,"noo!!");
        throw new ApiException("problem connecting to server " + e.getMessage(),e);
    }

    return retval;



}

}
```

Comment: what does the ApiException print to the log? if there is nothing, try logging the exception and post the log. for example, instead of `Log.d(logTag,"noo!!");`try `Log.d(logTag, e.getMessage());`

Comment: I do that it said 05-25 12:14:37.882: D/LastFMHelper(22953): Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Answer (score 0):

well theres your problem. you do not have internet permission, so your app cant connect to the server. Add this line at the top of the `<manifest>` - tag in your AppManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

I would suggest you read these guides about the AppManifest and how it handles permissions:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permissions

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons could be predicted if you don't give us the logs. I just predict the wrong:
maybe you have to put this snippet before request to server:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                }
```

Comment: the problem is with the internet permission (see comments on question). but this looks interesting. care to elaborate a little? what does this do?

Comment: StrictMode for network access results in a fatal error as for Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) or later, unless your app is targeting an API version before Honeycomb.t allows to setup policies in your application to avoid doing incorrect things. For example the following setup will crash your application if it violates some of the Android policies. StrictMode should only be used during development and not in your live application. Ref:Vogella